# PageLayout and Master Page

Tags: master-page, page-layout

How can I make a Page Layout to use participial Master-page.
What is happening is in my SharePoint page I am using green colour Image please see below, however if I change the Page-Layout to something else this image will disappear.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A page layout master page can be specified when you create your layout, if you go to Design Manager -> Edit Page Layouts -> Create a page layout. the prompt will ask you to select a master page. so as a solution you can create a new layout with the master page you need and copy the content of the old layout to it

Comment: thanks Mohamad, I will try your solution. however, what about the existing page layout can you edit them and change the Master Page?